# Maximum n so there exist two equal sum, 3-element subsets from a 9 element set of positive integers

Tags: combinatorics

$S$ is a 9 element subset of the set of positive integers $\{1, 2, 3, ..., n-1, n\}$. For all $S$, there exist two distinct three element subsets, $\{x, y, z\}$ and $\{a, b, c\}$, so that $x + y + z = a + b + c$, find the maximum value of $n$.
($\{x, y, z\}$ and $\{a, b, c\}$ are not necessarily disjoint)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but I often find putting bounds on $n$ can trigger useful thought.  For the lower bound, there are $84$ three element subsets of $S$, so there will always be two subsets with matching sum unless there are $84$ distinct sums.  The smallest the sum can be is $6$, so the sum of the largest three must be at least $89$ for this to fail.  If you have all of $1,2,3$, you can't also have two neighboring ones at the top end or two that differ by $2$, so this says $n \gt 32$.  At the other end, ${1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256}$ has no subsets with matching sum (think binary expansion), so $n \lt 256$.  I suspect it is much closer to the bottom end.

Comment: This [paper](http://fks.sk/~kubus/doc/201012ssd.pdf) gives a $9$ element set with all distinct subset sums (not just subsets of size $3$), with largest number being $161$. So this reduces upper bound here to $161$. And there are $84$ subsets of size $3$ in a $9$ element set. So the lower bound above is in fact $29$.

Comment: @polkjh:  you are right, I corrected it.  The lower bound is actually $33$-I updated the argument a bit.